# Can't get API proxy to work with SQS using CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, amazon-sqs

I'm following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@pranaysankpal/aws-api-gateway-proxy-for-sqs-simple-queue-service-5b08fe18ce50) and I can get it all working just fine using the console. I've converted the SQS queue and API creation to CloudFormation, but can't get the API method integration to work. I've used Former2 to convert the working method to CloudFormation (shown below) but I continue to get this error:

```
Invalid mapping expression specified: Validation Result: 
warnings : [],
errors : [Invalid mapping expression specified: application/x-www-form-urlencoded] 
(Service: AmazonApiGateway; Status Code: 400; Error Code: BadRequestException; 
Request ID: 1e40fc86-af05-4698-a91a-c1fa8930ee10; Proxy: null)
```

The CloudFormation template for my POST method is as follows:

```
  ApiPostMsgMethod:
    DependsOn: 'SqsQueue'
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
    Properties: 
      ApiKeyRequired: false
      AuthorizationType: NONE
      HttpMethod: POST
      Integration:
          Credentials: !GetAtt ApiSqsSendMsgRole.Arn
          IntegrationHttpMethod: POST
          IntegrationResponses:
            - StatusCode: '200'
          PassthroughBehavior: NEVER
          RequestParameters: 
            integration.request.header.Content-Type: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
          RequestTemplates: 
            application/json : 'Action=SendMessage&MessageBody=$input.body'
          TimeoutInMillis: 1200
          Type: AWS
          Uri: !Join
            - ""
            - - !Sub "arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:sqs:path/${AWS::AccountId}/"
              - !Sub ${EnvironmentName}-queue
      MethodResponses:
          - StatusCode: 200
      OperationName: PostSqsItem
      ResourceId: !Ref SqsResource
      RestApiId: !Ref SqsRestApi
```

While Former2 returns the following template from a working POST method:

```
    httpMethod: POST
    authorizationType: NONE
    apiKeyRequired: false
    requestParameters: <empty object>
    methodResponses:
        200:
            statusCode: 200
            responseModels:
                application/json: Empty
    methodIntegration:
        type: AWS
        httpMethod: POST
        uri: arn:aws:apigateway:###:sqs:path/###/###
        credentials: arn:aws:iam::###:role/###
        requestParameters:
            integration.request.header.Content-Type: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        requestTemplates:
            application/json: Action=SendMessage&MessageBody=$input.body
        passthroughBehavior: NEVER
        timeoutInMillis: 29000
        cacheNamespace: ###
        integrationResponses:
            200:
                statusCode: 200
                responseTemplates:
                    
    restApiId: ###
    resourceId: ###
```

My references and substitutions appear to be working, but I still get this integration error. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the trouble seems to me is coming from here

```yaml
integration.request.header.Content-Type: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

It should be something like

```yaml
integration.request.header.Content-Type: "'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'"
```

Comment: Yep, that did it. Subtle, I did not catch that in the documentation.